# User Participation in Help and Improvement Review Queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, help-improvement

I mostly active on Reviews on SO. Since last 4-5 months, I noticed that total number of daily reviews done in "Help and Improvement" are degrade than other review queues on daily basis.

When "Help and Improvement" review queue launched, then more users take actively participate in Edit/Improve the posts, but now very few users take actively participate, and also very few users(3 to 5 users) able to complete their daily quota of 20 reviews.

If you see the "Help and Improvement" All time Stats then you realized that mostly users complete their 1000 reviews bucket to earn badge, and left further reviewing.

Below is the Today's Comparison between Different Review Queues till this time to summarize the better picture:-

- Close Votes Review Today till now :- **1600+ counting** (Total quota completed by **more than 20 users**)
- Low Quality Posts Review Today till now :- **2550+ counting** (Total quota completed by **more than 20 users**)
- Triage Review Today till now :- **7500+ counting** (Total quota completed by **more than 20 users**)
- Suggested Edits Review Today till now :- **3900+ counting**(Total quota completed by **more than 20 users**)
- First Posts Review Today till now :- **1810+ counting**(Total quota completed by **more than 20 users**)
- Reopen Votes Review Today till now :- **416+ counting**(Total quota completed by **11 users**)
- **Help and Improvement Review Today till now :- 150+ counting**(Total quota completed by **3 users**)
- Late Answers Review Today till now :- **750+ counting**(Total quota completed by **14 users**)

I also noticed that some days the total number of review done in Help and Improvement Review queue remain under 100.

Is their any action plan needed to attract more users so that they actively take participate in "Help and Improvement" review queue? or no need to worry?

Comment: There's just not that many reviews in that queue whenever I visit.  That's the main reason I don't do much in H&I.

Comment: @ryanyuyu :- I agreed that H&I have lower review in total but that's also apply to other queues such as Late Answer or so

Comment: Yeah, and my participation in FP/LA is also low for the same reason.  Although not quite as low as H&I.

Comment: but still if you do the comparison, then total daily H&I review are remains lower than LA/FP. I am not saying that H&I always have only one or two reviews, I see many times more than 50 review shown on main review page counter but after one or two review list become empty

Comment: And thats exactly my question what else we need to do to invite/attract more user in H&I queue

Comment: Oh my bad, I misinterpreted your question.  I'm not sure it's that big of a deal, but yes it does seem to have less activity.

Comment: Personally, I got burnt out on seeing 9 out of 10 question in the H&I being ones the OP has to edit because people don't get "Requires Editing"...

Comment: some times, I saw question where OP have less reputation to add image or bad code formatting/error formatting. and where we want OP needs to modify question, then why that's question in review queue. Its here so that we can improve it dont it otherwise skip is best

Comment: The majority of the stuff I've seen in the H&I is either utter garbage, or already pretty decent. Too many people are choosing "looks ok" for posts that can use some editing, and "requires editing" for posts that should just be closed outright. Somewhere in there people are choosing "requires editing" when they should be choosing "looks ok".