# Remove the Help & Improvement queue!

Tags: feature-request, help-improvement

This is intentionally a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) because it's a proposal for a change in an existing feature.

I just swamped through a dozen or so posts from the "Help & Improvement" review queue and managed to click on "question is very low quality" for virtually all of them. This action appears impactless since it doesn't translate to a Close Vote.

This is surely not the intended outcome of using this review queue. My feature request is to **remove this queue** until it becomes useful by some fundamental changes.

Such a step, of course, relies on the community agreeing with my view on its uselessness *or* lack of clarity on usage. The consensus to date ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289998/help-and-improvement-needs-help), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346052/help-and-improvement-needs-improvement), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290862/flagging-questions-in-help-and-improvement), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312178/user-participation-in-help-and-improvement-review-queue), [5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344238/how-to-close-a-question-in-the-help-and-improvement-queue), [6](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359995/help-and-improvement-is-dead-can-we-please-let-it-die)) seems to agree.

The main gripe seems to be a reviewer can't *easily* VTC a really poor question which reaches this queue, which seems like a waste of valuable resources (i.e. reviewer time).

If the problem is upstream, i.e. posts incorrectly feed H&I, then there's an even stronger argument: the small number of posts reaching H&I will become even smaller.

Comment: *This action appears impactless since it doesn't translate to a Close Vote.* No, but it does translate in a VLQ flag and from my own experience impact your declined flag rate ...

Comment: @rene, Fair point. I guess my general issue (as also raised by others) is that if I've taken the time to review a post, I should have the ability to VTC it if it's inadequate. Each review queue may have a different name, but internally we are asking ourselves the same questions each time (Is this a good question for SO? How can it be made into a good Q&A?).

Comment: Posts that end up here usually come from Triage reviews ending in "Requires Editing", am I correct?

Comment: @JessedeBruijne yes, that path is severely broken. Maybe everyone who clicks "requires edting" should get an instant review ban.... my bet is that the quality of the reviews will increase drastically with that measure ...

Comment: There's probably been a dozen questions about this too, but the "Requires Editing" button is often used when the reviewer wants the OP to edit it (add extra information, add MVCE, etc.), and therefore they cannot be helped by other reviewers in H&I, resulting in OP's 'frustration'.

Comment: @JessedeBruijne, Yes, a few of the links in my post refers to this common problem. But if you remove these posts from H&I, are you left with much else? I suspect not given its already small size.

Comment: Most reviews that I've seen in H&I are just very minor edits. They don't teach new users how to use the site, which I thought was the idea behind this queue. I see no added value for this queue, so in favor of dropping it.

Comment: @S.L.Barth _They don't teach new users how to use the site, which I thought was the idea behind this queue._ That's what the [First Posts] queue is for, isn't it?

Comment: So then triage would just become _Looks OK_ or _Unsalvageable_, where _Unsalvageable_ is pretty much the same options you have in the CV queue (except you can flag spam/rude/mod)? If we remove H&I, then triage isn't really distinct from the CV queue, except they're fed from different sources.

Comment: @JessedeBruijne When H&I was introduced, guidance was [explicitly one of the goals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287466/812149). There's some overlap between FP on the one hand, and Triage/H&I on the other hand. Since the latter two fail, I say we just roll them into First Posts.

Comment: How about some intermediary function: We remove H&I but keep "Needs improvement". Flagging Needs Improvement will then pull up a flag menu, where users can pick reasons what is lacking in this post, Needs MCVE; Too broad; etc. After amassing X number of Needs Improvement flags the post is hidden on the site, and only visible to OP, together with a notification that this happend, he should improve his post, and what communitys major concern with his post is.

Comment: H&I is already a 'close vote feeder queue' AFAIC, and I gave up at 250 reviews. If a close vote could be cast from the queue and would count as a review (or better still, the queue actually contained on-topic questions which would benefit from a polish) I might spend some time there but for now, meh.

Comment: @StephenKennedy Well done for getting to 250, I gave up after 1...

Comment: @StephenKennedy I don't think it is. Should dig up Shog's flowchart on this.... EDIT: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage It indeed doesnt.

Comment: @Luuklag Not literally, no. But my workflow would be open review item and find that it is off-topic, open in new tab, vote to close, close tab, skip to next item, and repeat, only occasionally stopping to edit something.

Comment: @Luuklag That chart demonstrates another problem: the infinite _Triage_ -> Requires editing -> _H&I queue_ -> VLQ flag -> _Triage_ -> requires editing loop. That's half the problem here I guess.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt, I'd say related.. There's a difference: that was a `[discussion]` 6 months ago; today it's a `[feature-request]`.

Comment: @Luuklag Triage already has the ability to flag a post for those types of problems (and more).  The problem is that people that see a bad post just refuse to actually use said functionality and instead click "requires editing" on every bad post instead, even though it can't be edited into good shape and should have instead been flagged as too broad, unclear, lacking a reproducible example, etc.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth that definetly is a problem as well. Wouldn't be the first time I saw a post for the third time in H&I.

Comment: @jpp Just because a question is mis-tagged doesn't mean you need to ask it again with the correct tags.  All you need to do is edit it to fix the tags.

Comment: @StephenKennedy That is what I do now and then as well, but pretty time consuming.

Comment: I just noticed that they changed the Triage help popup to "Requires Editing for questions that you can make clear and answerable by editing" (it used to say that "Requires Editing" is for questions that need edits by the author). I wonder when they changed it and if it has had any positive effect on Help and Improvement.

Comment: @Servy, yes they have ways to flag a post to be closed, deleted and forgot about. But thinking of the being welcoming aspect as well I think my suggestion is some sort of hybrid of welcomeness and deletion. It also might let people think a bit more before clicking Needs Improvement, as that currently is the easiest escape from the review. It like the failproof choice you don't have to think about. On second though we should just remap that button to the skip button ;)

Comment: @DonaldDuck It was a very recent change.  I want to say last month some time (plus or minus a few weeks).  The problem now is that there are simply thousands of reviewers who have trained themselves that "requires editing" is what you click for every bad post you see.  They don't go reading the guidelines because *they've already read them* and they "know" that they're supposed to click "requires editing" for every bad post, and have had it ingrained in them over the course of many years.

Comment: @Luuklag Closing a post that merits closure is not being unwelcoming.  The feature you described as being what you wanted is *literally exactly how closure works* to a tee.

Comment: Also I just noticed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/19867372) that once a question in the Help and Improvement queue gets closed, it leaves the queue. I got that question in Help and Improvement, was the fifth user to vote to close it from outside of the queue and when I went back to the queue it was no longer reviewable. So the best thing to to with bad questions in Help and Improvement is to vote to close them.